# Finding a limit using polar co-ordinates.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Let us suppose that we have to find the following limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y).$$
Can we solve such a limit using polar co-ordinates? I have seen the following method somewhere on the internet:

If we take $x=r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta$, then the above limit becomes:$$\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos\theta,r \sin\theta).$$
But solving a limit this way does not cover all the paths passing through $(0,0)$, because whatever $\theta$ we choose, that $\theta$ gives a straight line path through $(0,0)$, it does cover the path like $x^2, \ x^3$ etc.

Comment: You're right that $\theta$ can't be treated as a constant. See for example [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969960/continuity-of-begincasesxyy2-x4y2-textif-x-y-neq0-0-0-tex/2970193#2970193) (or many others on this site).

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the limit  is $L$ you have to show that $f(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)\to L$ as $r \to 0$ uniformly for $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: Uniformly means, for all $\theta$, $f$ tends to $L$. Am I right? (But my question is: whatever $\theta$ we choose, it gives a straight line path only, it does not cover all the paths)