# Show that a multivariate function is continuous at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I'm working on this problem:

Let:
$$ 
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{3/5}y^{2/5}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} 
&\text{if} \ (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
0  &\text{if} \ (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

I want to show that $f$ is continuous at the origin.

So my scratch/set up is:

$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0 \ s.t. \ |(x,y)-(\overline{x},\overline{y})|<\delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(\overline{x},\overline{y})|<\varepsilon$

So I get:

$|f(x,y) - f(\overline{x},\overline{y})|=\left|{\cfrac{x^{3/5}y^{2/5}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0}\right|<\varepsilon$

If we convert to polar coordinates and utilise the Pythagorean Identity:

$x = r\cos{\theta}, \ \ \ y = r\sin{\theta}$

The function *should* reduce down to (an image of the steps taken are below):

$\left|{\cfrac{x^{3/5}y^{2/5}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0}\right|=(\cos^{3}{\theta}\cdot\sin^{2}{\theta})^{1/5}<\varepsilon$

If we were working in the (x,y) plane the sinusoidal functions would be bounded above by 1, however I'm not 100% sure what they are bounded by in polar form. Am I on the right track for showing continutiy?

**SCRATCH WORKINGS:**

[image]

Comment: Plz read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970193/8581) carefully.

Comment: See a quick sketch of the [function](https://www.google.com/search?q=x^(3%2F5)*y^(2%2F5)%2Fsqrt(x^2%2By^2))

Answer (score 1):

You arrive at the conclusion that for any $(x, y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\neq (0, 0)$, you have that
$$
f(x, y) = (\cos^3\theta\cdot \sin^2\theta)^{1/5}
$$
for *arbitrary* $\theta$. What happens if I choose $\theta = \pi/4$? What about $\theta = 0$? What does this tell you about the continuity at the point $(0, 0)$?

Comment: My gut is telling me that at $(0,0)$ the continuity at this point isn't dependant on $\theta$, I think I am getting the idea in my head but finding it hard to put to words/logic

Comment: If I look at the sequence $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n \cos(0), 1/n \sin(0)) = (1/n, 0)$, then note that $(x_n, y_n)\to (0, 0)$ yet all $(x_n, y_n)\neq (0, 0)$. By the sequential characterization of continuity, we expect to see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n, y_n) = f(0, 0) = 0$, and here that is indeed what we see. However, we expect to see this for any old sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ converging to zero. What happens if we instead look at the sequence $(x_n', y_n') = (1/n \cos(\pi/4), 1/n \sin(\pi/4)) = \left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}} , \frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}} \right)$? What happens to $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n', y_n')$?

Comment: Oh! It still converges to $(0,0)$, and that would be because sin and cosine are bounded by 1, so regardless of what value we have, the convergence will eventually behave like $1/n$ for sufficiently large n.

Comment: @Sprawk48 ???? Please repeat your calculations for the above case. $x$ and $y$ go to zero, but the function does not.

Comment: @Andrei Right, I got ahead of myself. Yeah, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x'_n,y'_n) \neq 0$ from the second case.  I still feel like I'm at a loss for how to bring this logic to show that the original function is continuous.

Comment: @Sprawk48 the point is that when $x=y$, no matter how small is $x>0$, the function is equal to $1/\sqrt(2)\approx 0.707$. Then, I can choose $\varepsilon=0.1$. There is no $\delta$ such that if $|(x,x)|<\delta$ then $|f(x,x)-0|<\varepsilon$. So the function has a discontinuity.